# get_post_meta giving errors while creating a metabox

Tags: metabox

i was following atutorial on how to make a custom metabox to  wordpress post but
its giving errors

here is my full code

```
//Add Metabox
function diwp_custom_metabox(){
    //add_meta_box(metabox_id,metabox name,callback function,metabox location(page,post,custom post etc),context-(normal,side,advanced),piority())
    add_meta_box('diwp-metabox','My Custom Metabox','diwp_post_metabox_callback','post','normal');
}

//add action
add_action('add_meta_boxes','diwp_custom_metabox');
//metabox callback function

function diwp_post_metabox_callback(){
    // echo 'hi i am diwp metabox';
    ?>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="label">Post Reading Time</div>
      <div class="fields">
        <input type="text" name="_diwp_reading_time" value="<?php get_post_meta($post->ID,'post_reading_time',true); ?>">
      </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function diwp_save_custom_metabox(){
    // update_post_meta($post_id,$meta_key,$meta_value,$prev_value);
    global $post;
    if(isset($_POST['_diwp_reading_time'])){
        update_post_meta($post->ID,'post_reading_time',$_POST['_diwp_reading_time']);
    }
}

add_action('save_post','diwp_save_custom_metabox');
```

error screen shot
[image]

any help will be appreciated ,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error there clearly says that there's an undefined variable (`post`) in your metabox callback function.

So you need to define `$post` in your function head:

```php
// The $post variable is passed by WordPress.
function diwp_post_metabox_callback( $post )
```

And you should also do the same to `diwp_save_custom_metabox()` function (which is hooked to [`save_post`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/)):

```php
// Here, $post is the second parameter.
function diwp_save_custom_metabox( $post_ID, $post ) {
    // ...
}

// Don't forget to set the 4th parameter to 2:
add_action( 'save_post', 'diwp_save_custom_metabox', 10, 2 );
```

Or alternatively, use `get_post()` and not the `global` call:

```php
// Here, $post is the second parameter.
function diwp_save_custom_metabox( $post_ID ) {
    $post = get_post( $post_ID ); // like this
//  global $post;                 // not this

    // ...
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'diwp_save_custom_metabox' );
```

Comment: hello thanks for reply and code works but can you please explain what 10 and 2 means in this line add_action( 'save_post', 'diwp_save_custom_metabox', 10, 2 ); ..i have seen that im few tutorials but didnt understand what that means? and to output the meta field data on front end i am using this code echo get_post_meta( $post->ID,  'post_reading_time', true ); is it ok?

Comment: Yes, that's fine. And check out the docs for `add_action()` [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/), but the `10` means the callback's priority - if there were 4 callbacks hooked to `save_post`, that priority determines the position of your own callback, e.g. is it the first or last one that executes. And the `2` is the number of args your callback accepts, but you need to check the hook docs (e.g. [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/save_post/) for `save_post`) to know all the args for that specific hook.

Comment: You should also [validate, sanitize and escape user data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data), e.g. use `esc_attr()` with the `<input>`'s `value` and `esc_html()` when displaying the value, e.g. `echo esc_html( get_post_meta( ... ) )`.

Comment: ok i have used wp nonce along with esc_html let me know if its ok ..check here ...   https://pastebin.com/d3Y4vS3x